# How to create a HTML table of file names from mySQL database and their corresponding files(hyperlink) in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I have a form that submits a file to the server in the folder **uploads** and also saves the file name(as stored in the server) as well as other file details in my database.
Now what I'm trying to do, is create a HTML table that displays file details as well as the corresponding file(In hyperlink of course).

Is there any way to this? An idea I had is to link the file name to the corresponding file in my **uploads/** directory but I have no idea on how to achieve that.

Here is my table **uploaded_content** where the form data is stored in my database

```
================================================
id |Description | filename                     |
------------------------------------------------
1  |Information | 3223-2323-4334-32-slajjjq.txt|
2  |Users       | 3223-2323-4344-33-slik.txt   |
================================================
```

And here is an example of how my `uploads/` directory looks like (Notice that their names are saved in my database)

```
3223-2323-4334-32-slajjjq.txt
3223-2323-4344-33-slik.txt
```

So now I want to create a HTML table with the following columns

```
id |Description | filename  |File
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Is your upload directory accessible to the public?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is accessible to the public

Comment: Is an SQL database?

Comment: You could use an anchor tag <a href="/uploads/<the file name>">download</a>. I must warn you, if you do not validate the file type on the server side when uploading, a hacker could upload a php file and execute some commands on your server.

Comment: @Valentino there is a tag mysqli.

Comment: @Valentino I had mistakenly wrote "class" instead of "table" for **uploaded_content** I have corrected it right now, you may have a look at the table now

Comment: Sorry, I missed the tag. So it's just querying and fetching from the database and build an HTML table with the data. Did you try to use the PHP `mysqli` class? If so, please add in the question what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the best way to do it, but i just wanna show you how to do that.

Step 1 - Create mysql DB.

```
CREATE TABLE `uploaded_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `filename` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Step 2 - Insert data to this DB.

```
INSERT INTO `uploaded_content` (`id`, `description`, `filename`) VALUES
(1, 'Information', '3223-2323-4334-32-slajjjq.txt'),
(2, 'Users', '3223-2323-4344-33-slik.txt');
```

Step 3 - Make config.php:

```
<?php
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stack', 'root', '');
    $q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_content WHERE id");
    $f = $q->fetchAll();
?>
```

Step 4 - Create index.php with this code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Description</th> 
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Download link</th>
    </tr>
<?php 
foreach ($f as $g) :?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $g['id']; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $g['description']; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $g['filename']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="https://example.com/uploads/<?php echo $g['filename']; ?>">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

When you finish that, you get html page like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Description</th> 
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Download link</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Information</td>
      <td>3223-2323-4334-32-slajjjq.txt</td>
      <td><a href="https://example.com/uploads/3223-2323-4334-32-slajjjq.txt">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Users</td>
      <td>3223-2323-4344-33-slik.txt</td>
      <td><a href="https://example.com/uploads/3223-2323-4344-33-slik.txt">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to say, than you very much, It works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a query to get the list from the database.
2. Use that list to build your HTML table.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `a_files` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO `a_files` (`id`, `Description`, `filename`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Information', 'some-file-000-111-222.txt'),
    (2, 'Users', 'some-file-000-111-223.txt');
```

Code:

```
 class FileLister {
    const UPLOAD_DIR = '/uploads';
    public function makeList()
    {
        $db = [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'user' => 'app',
            'password' => 'aaaa',
            'database' => 'sss',
        ];
        $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$db['database']};host={$db['host']}";

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db['user'], $db['password']); 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `a_files`";
            $rs = $pdo->query($sql);
            foreach($rs as $row) {
                // echo print_r($row, true) . PHP_EOL;
                echo sprintf("<A href=\"https://sample.com%s/%s\">%s</A>\n",
                    self::UPLOAD_DIR,
                    $row['filename'],
                    $row['Description']);
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
$lister = new FileLister;
$lister->makeList();
```

Output:

```
<A href="https://sample.com/uploads/some-file-000-111-222.txt">Information</A>
<A href="https://sample.com/uploads/some-file-000-111-223.txt">Users</A>
```